# SQL Insert along with matching audit at same time from app

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got an app that will insert lines to table [P_R], which has first field being [PrimaryKey]. 
Now I have to add another table, [Actions] with fields [PrimaryKey],[P_R_PK],[User],[ActionTime].

When the app inserts a line to [P_R], I don't know what the PrimaryKey will be, but I have to simultaneously insert to [Actions] with the value in [P_R_PK] being the PrimaryKey I just added to [P_R]. How do I get this PrimaryKey value to [P_R_PK]?

For reference, I'm using a vb.net windows form with a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a stored procedure to add the records to [P_R], you can call another stored procedure in the first that includes the primary key. For example:

```
CREATE PROC AddToP_R
@field1 varchar(10),
@field2...10
AS
BEGIN
declare @pk int --primary key that's created upon inserting

--insert into [P_R]
INSERT INTO [P_R]
VALUES (@field1,...)

--set the var we created to be the primary key
SET @pk = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--call second proc
EXEC Second_Proc @pk
END
```

If you need other fields in the second stored procedure, include them in the first procedure parameter list.

Another way would be to a wrapper stored procedure that calls both the other two. For this to work, you would need an output variable in the first procedure to return the primary key. For example:

```
CREATE PROC AddWrapper
@fieldsforfirstproc...,
@fieldsforsecondproc...
AS
BEGIN
declare @outputVar int --primary key
EXEC firstproc @fieldsforfirstproc..., @outputvar output --adds the record to the first table and returns @outputvar as the primary key

EXEC secondproc @fieldsforsecondproc..., @outputvar --adds the record to the second table using @output var
END
```

I prefer the second option because it removes logic from the first procedure that doesn't need to be there. However, the first procedure would be slightly different to how I showed earlier.

```
CREATE PROC AddToP_R
@field1 varchar(10),
@field2...10,
@pk int OUTPUT --primary key that's created upon inserting
AS
BEGIN
--insert into [P_R]
INSERT INTO [P_R]
VALUES (@field1,...)

--set the var we created to be the primary key
SET @pk = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Comment: Can all of this be sent through an OleDbConnection? I've only ever used simple one line strings before.

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. I don't see why not, though I'm not familiar with OleDbConnection. My guess, is yes. I personally use SqLConnection which also inherits from DbConnection. I'm getting off work now, but I'll look around when I get home unless you've found a solution by then.

Comment: This might help...
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/ole-db/stored-procedures-calling)

Comment: Thank you. I did stumble upon that page. From what I understand, stored procedures are stored on the server, correct? That does seem like the long term goal, but I've just started playing around with creating transactions and procedures, which I'm going to continue exploring now.
This stuff gets pretty intense!

Comment: Stored procedures are typically stored in database. Are you using SQL Management studio? If so, you can create them in there and call them from your VB project. But yeah! Hope I helped some!

Comment: Definitely! And yeah, I did look to create them in there, but I seem to not have the same tools that MS's page is talking about, so I'll put that on the back burner for now. Still, learned something new today :)

Comment: I'll take a look at it some if I get a chance tomorrow and see if I can find out a way to call them using OleDbConnection. Hopefully I'll be able to post back tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve it by using `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the `INSERT`.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T table (id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, value int)

INSERT INTO @T (value) VALUES (2)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() new_pk
```

I would also consider doing it all in one stored procedure within a transaction. Given that you are inserting into more than one table, a transaction would allow you to roll back should anything go wrong.

Comment: Personally, if executing this via VB, I would execute a stored procedure command (by setting the command type), and pass all of the necessary values/data in as parameters). Though if you wanted to, you could just return your new PK to the code from an initial command.

Comment: Where does the table name get entered in the code you provided?

Comment: I've used a table variable, so rather than inserting into `@T`, you would insert into your table - `INSERT INTO [TableName]`.